# Pusher Channels: Public or Private?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pusher

General question regarding implementation. I have an app that lets a user (user 1) subscribe to another user (user 2). If user 2 publishes some information, I want a real-time notification to be sent to user 1. However, maybe user 2 has thousands of subscribers that all should receive a notification.

My question, should I have a private channel (i.e. user 2 channel) that everyone subscribes to since they subscribe to user 2? Or, is a public channel sufficient? There shouldn't be any sensitive data published by user 2, but since only those users that subscribe to another user should be notified, does that need to be a private channel?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about strictly controlling who is able to subscribe to each channel then I would just stick to public channels. You only need to worry about private channels when you are worried about who is able to read the potentially sensitive data on the channel.